# Vue - script does not work in <script setup> element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have working widget from Atlassian, when I use it in html file, behaviour is as expected:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script data-jsd-embedded data-key=<key> data-base-url=https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com src=https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com/assets/embed.js></script>
</head>
</html>
```

but when I use it directly in vue component then I can't see widget:

```
 <template>
<p>test</p>
</template>
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';



onMounted(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('data-jsd-embedded', '');
  script.setAttribute('data-key', '<key>');
  script.setAttribute('data-base-url', 'https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com');
  script.setAttribute('src', 'https://jsd-widget.atlassian.com/assets/embed.js');
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
</script>
```

I have tested different approaches but without result, no errors/warnings in console log.

Comment: as you are using `<script setup>` that implies you're using some sort of build framework (vite at a guess) ... why not just put that `<script>` in the `index.html`? `I have tested different approaches` what other approaches have you tested?

Comment: It is syntax from Vue composition api and I need it in more complex components, without script setup I cannot use built in features. 

Other approaches - combinations with different missing tags, missing tag ids, script loading with waiting etc.

Comment: You can see in the script that DOMContentLoaded is used. You can safely assume that it relies on that it's not created asynchronously and should be loaded early on the page

Comment: `It is syntax from Vue composition api` - no way!! is it? I never knew.

Comment: I am not experienced in FE/JS/Vue, looking at my question it is quite easy to deduce, so not sure what value has your comment, I just wanted to add more context, because I was not sure what info is missing.

Comment: I would, as it was said earlier, put that script in a static part of index.html. Is there any reason not doing it so?

Comment: @Mono yes, I've created project around year ago, when I've started learning and completely forgot about this file, it is working :) and ideal place for such functionalities, please add answer and I will accept it, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script imports are usually done in a static part of an application in a header of index.html.